# How do you save the result of a variable in javascript that is generated by a function?

Tags: javascript, html

let's say you have the following **Javascript** code:

```
function random() {
    var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number;

    return number;
};

function searchE(number) {
    var english = englishID[number];
    document.getElementById('english').innerHTML = english; 
};

function searchJ(number) {
    var root = root[number];
    var masu = masu[number];
    var te = te[number];
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = root; 
    document.getElementById('masu').innerHTML = masu;
    document.getElementById('te').innerHTML = te; 
};

function process() {  
    var number = random();
    searchE(number);
    searchJ(number);
};
```

My problem is when the code is that only the random number and the `searchE()` results are outputted. I believe the problem is that I'm either not doing `var result = moof()` correctly or not returning a result from `moof`properly.

Can somebody please tell me how to make it work? Thank you for your time.

Comment: you would be better off if you did a jsfiddle or something to demonstrate how you are using this

Comment: `ploof(result);` - you ignore the returned value here. and `doof(result);` here as well ... spoof, ploof and doof all return `undefined`

Comment: Where is `englishId` defined?

Comment: englishID is an array, would you like me to paste it because it is huge?

Comment: Remove your example and use your real code, you just made the question that much harder to answer

Comment: `var root = root[number];` - What? Is there a separate array `root` ? This makes no sense. What console errors are you getting? Please post a [MCVE]. By breaking the problem down you might find the issue yourself, if not you will make our lives *much* easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here:

```
function searchJ(number) {
  var root = root[number];
  var masu = masu[number];
  var te = te[number];
```

`var`s get hoisted, so to the interpreter, it looks like:

```
function searchJ(number) {
  var root;
  var masu;
  var te;
  root = root[number];
  masu = masu[number];
  te = te[number];
```

So when you try to access those arrays/objects in the outer scope (I'm assuming those variables exist in the outer scope, right?), you're actually referencing the currently `undefined` variables in the inner scope. Use variable names *different* from the ones used in the outer scope:

```
function searchJ(number) {
  var foundRoot = root[number];
  var foundMasu = masu[number];
  var foundTe = te[number];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! To my disappointment I wanted to display Japanese characters and instead it displayed this: ãŸã™,ã“ãŸãˆã‚‹
ãŸã—ã¾ã™,ã“ãŸãˆã¾ã™
ãŸã—ã¦,ã“ãŸãˆã¦ So I'm going to have to scan the internet again

Comment: That sounds like an encoding problem, not a Javascript problem, probably